# eglCreateContext failed(3003) error

Tags: opengl-es, egl

I runned PowerVR SDK'S Example program(solution and built program both), but every program become "eglCreateContext failed(3003)" error
I cannot found what's error is this. There are any one who know this problem?

```
INFORMATION: Trying to create context for all configs.
INFORMATION: EGL context creation: EGL_KHR_create_context supported
INFORMATION: Failed to create context for any configs. Tried 9 configs.
INFORMATION: OpenGL ES 3.1 NOT supported. Trying lower version...
INFORMATION: Trying to create context for all configs.
INFORMATION: Failed to create context for any configs. Tried 9 configs.
INFORMATION: OpenGL ES 3.0 NOT supported. Trying lower version...
INFORMATION: Trying to create context for all configs.
INFORMATION: Failed to create context for any configs. Tried 9 configs.
INFORMATION: OpenGL ES 2.0 NOT supported. Trying lower version...
CRITICAL: === FATAL: COULD NOT FIND COMPATIBILITY WITH ANY OPENGL ES VERSION ===
INFORMATION: Unspecified target API -- Setting to max API level : Unknown
INFORMATION: EGL context creation: EGL_KHR_create_context supported...
INFORMATION: Trying to get OpenGL ES version : -1.-1
INFORMATION: EGL context creation: EGL_IMG_context_priority supported! Setting context HIGH priority (default)...
```

Comment: The program states that it cannot find any compatible OpenGL ES version. What graphics card are you using? Are your drivers up to date, or even installed?

Comment: @SporreKing I updated all graphic driver already(Geforce & Intel)

Comment: And what graphicscard are you using?

Comment: @SporreKing GeForce GT 520M